# How do I turn off notifications globally in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I turn off notifications globally in visual studio code. Not individual notifications from plugins, but every notification.

These are the popups that slide in from the top, displaying Error/Info/Upgrade/Activity messages.

It would be nice if this is system wide setting.

[image: Notification dialog]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 15):

Couldn't find a simple way to do this through VSCode's configuration. One way to hack this temporarily that seems to work though is `cmd-p`, enter `> developer` choose options with `toggle developer tools`. Chrome inspector opens. To disable all toasts set the style `.notifications-toasts` to `display: none`.

You can also try:

/* append this to Microsoft VS Code/_/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css */

```css
.monaco-workbench > .notifications-toasts.visible {
  display: none;
}

.notifications-toasts {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The second solution worked (CSS was minified but a CTRL+F helped find the first part of the snippet). Thank you, these notifications were driving me insane! :)

Comment: careful when setting display to none.  I just made EVERYTHING in disappear, and now can't see any windows with which to revert my change.  Thankfully the change wasn't saved persistently.

Answer (score 8):

If you are referring to the "This extension has an update... etc" toasts that pop up from the blue status bar:

Right-click the bell icon and select 'Hide Notifications' from the menu.

Comment: Thank you, obvious once you realize it's there.

Answer (score 7):

It looks there will be a `Do not Disturb` mode in vscode v1.69 (it is in Insiders now).  It turns off all the notification pop-ups (warnings, info, etc.) but not for **errors**.

command: `Notifications: Toggle Do Not Disturb Mode`  (unbound by default)

or

click the bell icon in the lower right and click on the slashed-bell icon in the pop-up to enable Do Not Disturb mode.  Same to disable the mode.

There is also a setting to determine how Zen Mode and this Do Not Disturb mode will interact, see the setting:

`Zen Mode: Silent Notifications`

Comment: Thanks! Had to do `cmd + p` in Mac and type `Notifications: Toggle Do Not Disturb Mode` to activate the command. The only way to tell if you are in Do Not Disturb mode is to check if the bell on the lower right is slashed. A slashed bell indicates that Do Not Disturb Mode is active.

Answer (score -5):

Add this to settings.json:

"update.mode": "none",

Comment: This is for disabling auto-updates to VS Code, not for notifications.

Comment: This worked for me, not sure why it was voted down so much.